# how to set style for every individual character in a word or sentence?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display counts for my website visitors. Is it possible to display a number or text like as the following image.

[image: image of desired layout and styling]

If is it possible using html and css, Please suggest me or tell me other way to fix it?

Thanks in advance ....

Comment: You can have span for each letter and do it, but having a sentence or word and specifying css for each letter via CSS alone is not possible.

Comment: Please mark an answer as correct so that it could help others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost working using jquery

```js
var text=$('p').text()
for(var x=0;x<text.length;x++){
var newt='<span>'+text[x]+'</span>'
$('p').html($('p').html()+ newt)
}
```

```css
span{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:orange;
    border-radius:15px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>123456</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple.

Just slice the one box image with empty space. and set the background image and repeat-x, and every character you give line spacing

ex:

```
.counter
{
width:auto; 
background: url('../images/box.png') repeat-x;
letter-spacing: 50px /* each box letter gap */
height:60px;
display:inline-block;
font: bold 20px arial;
color:#000;
text-indent:10px
}
```

Try this.

Comment: hacky but smart as hell:)

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is use a `<span>` for each letter like so:

```
<p><span id='num1'>1</span><span id='num2'>2</span><span id='num3'>3</span><span id='num4'>4</span>
```

Then just add the styling for each letter indivdually using the id or you could just add inline styles for each span

```
<span style='color:blue;'>1</span> and so on...
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but then each of the digits need to be part of a seperate HTML element, each of them having the same style. So you would need to generate your HTML dynamically based on the count you have. If you hard code the HTML, then if tomorrow the count increases to a 5 digit number, you won't be able to handle it.
So it needs to be JS, HTML and CSS.